# Plotting more than 8 waypoints for non-business users in Google Map V2 in Android How? Status=MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED

Tags: android, google-maps

I am want to Draw Route between start point and end point and i have more than 8 way point Google does not allow more then 8 way-point for non-business users in Google Map V2 in Android 
Please suggest some ideas???

Comment: I have to go by plane on Sunday to reach as early as possible but there is no plane that day. Now you got many ideas. Just joking.. :) Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kousik/2pNKH/

Comment: Thnx ved for your answer. but i am working on Android application. so how can i use this code in android application. in android apps we are using Google map V2.